# Is there a law that forces an employee to pay into social security?

Tags: united-states, employment

When an employee receives a paycheck in the United States, one of the deductions from the check is social security. I once tried to get this removed from my paycheck and the payroll company told me that they can not do this. Due to this, I was wondering if there is some sort of law that requires employees to pay Social Security?

Comment: On what basis did you ask to have the deduction removed? IIRC there are some exceptions to the FICA tax but they are indeed exceptional.

Comment: I use my own retirement schemes (401K, IRA's, etc) and did not want to invest into SS as I felt my funds would have a greater ROI in those accounts.

Comment: social security isn't an investment scheme. It's a tax that pays for the retirement income of those who are retired today. When you retire, future workers will pay for your benefit check.

Comment: (I realize this is an old post.) @phoog So... a pyramid scheme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There sure is: the Federal Insurance Contributions Act (FICA).  See [26 USC 3101](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/3101).

> In addition to other taxes, there is hereby imposed on the income of every individual a tax equal to 6.2 percent of the wages (as defined in section 3121(a)) received by the individual with respect to employment (as defined in section 3121(b)).

Moreover, your employer is required to withhold this tax from your wages.  See Section 3102.

Comment: I'm generally aware that railroad workers are not covered by social security.  The categorical phrase in the quote "every individual" stands out since the IRS states this: "Because this is a separate system for railroad employers, payments subject to railroad retirement taxes are specifically excepted from FICA, FUTA, and the Self-Employment Contributions Act (SECA)."  I find other named exceptions plausible.  Are railroaders the only one?   https://www.irs.gov/businesses/railroad-retirement-tax-act-rrta-desk-guide-january-2009

Comment: @user662852: No, there are a number of other exceptions.  I happen to be one: state employees in certain states that have opted out of Social Security, provided there is a mandatory public employee retirement system in its place.  See https://www.ssa.gov/slge/index.htm.  Others include certain religious groups (e.g. Amish), student workers, nonresident aliens, etc.  See https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/General-Tax-Tips/Who-Is-Exempt-from-Paying-Social-Security-Tax-/INF19965.html

Comment: @user662852: Of course, any time a law says "every", it is free to then create exceptions.  But my point was just that in general, the payment of social security tax is mandatory and not voluntary, and that it is not possible to opt out solely because you don't wish to pay it.  That seemed to be OP's main question.